# Adobe Flex (Flash Builder) + RubyAMF error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, flexbuilder, rubyamf

I develop applications using Adobe Flex and Ruby (through Ruby AMF plugin). The problem is that when I try to make a simple query from the data base I get an error caused by a UTF-8 char that comes from the db. The error is as follows.

> > > > > > > > > RubyAMF >>>>>>>>> # took: 0.00011 secs
> > > > > > > > >                   RubyAMF >>>>>>>>> # took: 0.26820 secs
> > > > > > > > >                   incompatible character encodings: ASCII-8BIT and UTF-8
> > > > > > > > >                   /Users/paito/work/banquet/server/vendor/plugins/rubyamf_plugin/io/read_write.rb:226:in `writen'
> > > > > > > > >                   /Users/paito/work/banquet/server/vendor/plugins/rubyamf_plugin/io/amf_serializer.rb:219:in`write_amf3_string'
> > > > > > > > >                   /Users/paito/work/banquet/server/vendor/plugins/rubyamf_plugin/io/amf_serializer.rb:148:in `write_amf3'

My controller:

```
def list_posts
@posts = Post.all
respond_to do |format|
  format.amf  { render :amf => @posts }
end
```

end

Rails version: 3.0.7

Does anyone have a clue how I could get this solved? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

rubyamf_plugin doesn't fully support Rails 3 or Ruby 1.9. If you would like to use it, you'll need to go back to Rails 2 and Ruby 1.8. If you need to stay on Rails 3 and Ruby 1.9, https://github.com/warhammerkid/rails3-amf supports them but is missing many of the features that rubyamf_plugin includes.